# Lose the last (first) character by reversing

Tags: c, linux, posix

My reverse function dont give the last(first) character back if the file ended with character and not with "\n" (hex 0A). My system is Posix. Can anywhere help?
Output:

```
54
3. sor Csörnyeföl   //here failed "d" the last character
2. sor Szentendre
1. sor Budapest
```

Here is the Code:

```
void rf_revers(FILE *fp) {
    int i, size, start, loop, counter;
    char *buffer;
    char line[256];
    start = 0;
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fp);
    printf("%d\n", size); // for test that fseek/ftell giving me the right value
    buffer = malloc((size+1) * sizeof(char));

    for (i=0; i< size; i++) {
        fseek(fp, size-1-i, SEEK_SET);
        buffer[i] = fgetc(fp);

        if(buffer[i] == 10) {
            if(i != 0) {
                counter = 0;
                for(loop = i; loop > start; loop--) {
                    if((counter == 0) && (buffer[loop] == 10)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    line[counter] = buffer[loop];
                    counter++;
                }
                line[counter] = 0;
                start = i;
                printf("%s\n",line);
            }
        }
    }

    if(i > start) {
        counter = 0;
        for(loop = i; loop > start; loop--) {
            if((counter == 0) && ((buffer[loop] == 10) || (buffer[loop] == 0))) {
                continue;
            }
            line[counter] = buffer[loop];
            counter++;
        }
        line[counter] = 0;
        printf("%s\n",line);

        return;
    }
}
```

--[sorry for bad english]--

Comment: Have you tried running with a debugger and a small input file?

Comment: Instead of reading the file backwards, read it normally into a memory buffer, then *print out* the buffer backwards. Also, removing the last character in a memory buffer is very  easy, it's just changing the last character to the string terminator.

Comment: You're already allocating a buffer the size of the entire file. Is there some reason you don't just load the file in to that buffer, then reverse-iterate the buffer with `while (size--) putc(buffer[size], stdout);` ?

Comment: WhozCraig: that i have not correctly understand..

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Using `SEEK_CUR` with an offset of `- sizeof memory_buffer`would be nice (and better for large files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought about it, tried it out, but in time find the solution.

```
for(loop = i; loop >= start; loop--) { // change loop > start to >=
    if(/*(counter == 0) &&*/ (buffer[loop] == 10)) {
```

and:

```
if(i > start) {
    counter = 0;
    for(loop = i-1; loop > start; loop--) {
```